# QListWidget and Multiple Selection

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, qlistwidget

I have a regular `QListWidget` with couple of signals and slots hookedup. Everything works as I expect. I can update, retrieve, clear etc.

But the UI wont support multiple selections.

How do I 'enable' multiple selections for `QListWidget`? My limited experience with PyQt tells me I need to create a custom `QListWidget` by subclassing .. but what next?

Google gave me C++ answers but I'm looking for Python

http://www.qtforum.org/article/26320/qlistwidget-multiple-selection.html

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/11721-QListWidget-multi-selection

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't help with the Python specific syntax but you don't need to create any subclasses.

After your `QListWidget` is created, call `setSelectionMode()` with one of the multiple selection types passed in, probably `QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection` is the one you want. There are a few variations on this mode that you may want to look at.

In your slot for the `itemSelectionChanged()` signal, call `selectedItems()` to get a `QList` of `QListWidgetItem` pointers.

Comment: `extendedSelection`. That's what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 30):

For PyQT4 it's

```
QListWidget.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
```

Comment: For PySide it´s exactly the same.

Comment: This should be the selected answer, as the OP specified "*Google gave me C++ answers but I'm looking for Python*". For Qt5, `QAbstractItemView` is imported from `QtWidgets`.

Answer (score 14):

Example of getting multiple selected values in listWidget with multiple selection.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
class Test(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Test, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.listWidget.setSelectionMode(
            QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection
        )
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 211, 291))
        for i in range(10):
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem("Item %i" % i)
            self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.printItemText)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def printItemText(self):
        items = self.listWidget.selectedItems()
        x = []
        for i in range(len(items)):
            x.append(str(self.listWidget.selectedItems()[i].text()))

        print (x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Test()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

output :-

[image]

Comment: I checked many solutions and didn't work. but this works fine on [Py]QT 5.11.3

Comment: Thank you for providing an example code!

Answer (score 6):

Using PyQt5 you can set the SelectionMode of your QListWidget to allow multiple selections by using:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets    


QtWidgets.QListWidget.setSelectionMode(2)
```

where

- SelectionMode = 0 => NoSelection
- SelectionMode = 1 => SingleSelection
- SelectionMode = 2 => MultiSelection
- SelectionMode = 3 => ExtendedSelection
- SelectionMode = 4 => ContiguousSelection

[Reference](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionMode-enum)

In Qt Creator you find this option here:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

In addition, you can use list comprehension to get the selected items, for example

```
num_ITEMS=[item.text() for item in self.listWidget.selectedItems()]
```

Answer (score 3):

After searching for much time I found out they they changed this in PyQt6. Now you have to do the following:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QListWidget, QAbstractItemView
# ... all your other imports
class MyWidget(QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super(MyWidget, self).__init__()
    self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
    self.my_list_view = QListWidget()
    self.my_list_view.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SelectionMode.MultiSelection) # also try QAbstractItemView.SelectionMode.ExtendedSelection if you want the user to press CTRL for multiple selection
```

Basically you have to import the `QAbstractItemView` from the widgets and use the right selection mode