# Is there an Python-PyQt5 function for multiselecting from a list using QCombobox?

Tags: pyqt5, multi-select

I am trying to build a GUI with a dropdown for multi-select in python, PyQT5 but, the display is only showing single item instead of a dropdown. Is there a way to include the options as a drop down ?

Answer (score 0):

QlistWidget has the setSelectionMode: [QListWidget and Multiple Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008649/qlistwidget-and-multiple-selection)
But the combobox does not seem to have it. And I don't remember seeing a combobox with multi selection on.

Comment: I've implemented the same it works well, but instead of a dropdown, it shows once item at a time, appreciate any help.

Comment: I mean : I don't remember ever seeing a combobox with multi selection enabled, not in qt or any other widget library (in wx it is documented to be resticted to single selection https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.ComboBox.html )

Comment: So you probably have to do with listbox, and add a handle or button to shrink its size to 1 line when you don't use it. Would that fit your needs?

Comment: I was able to implement multi selection check box with QComboBox, any idea on how to get checked items from the QComboBox?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't select multiple item from a QComboBox instance. It can be used to select only one item at once. If you want to have multiple selection in your widget have to use a QListView/Widget.